# При изменении масштаба иконки залазят под ссылки в списке

Tags: html

Есть список и и при изменении масштаба экрана ссылки смещяються и под них залазят иконки.Как исправить?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: ;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.top-nav,
.top-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/Qn6jzD5/top-section-background.png);
}

.top-nav {
  padding-left: 25%;
}

.top-nav li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.top-nav a,
.panel a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.top-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel a {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-section">
      <ul class="top-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Стоимость</span>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rtBn7XY/badge1.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Заказать путёвку</span>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FnPN9PJ/badge2.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Виртуальный тур</span>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/n0RZtTg/badge3.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Контакты</span>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/BfF3c3S/badge4.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- top-nav -->
      <div class="panel">
        <a href="">Рус</a><a href="">Каз</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: Логично, а как они должны туда поместится? используйте @media